# How to change image size without scaling in GIMP

Tags: gimp

For example, the original size is 800x800. I want to change it into 400x400, preserving only the upper left corner and discarding the data outside the new region. In mspaint I can do this via File->Properties, but I can't find a similar function within gimp.

Comment: You're looking for 'crop'. I've no idea where it is in Gimp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From GIMP documentation
[4.5. Crop An Image](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-crop.html):

Use menu *Tools > Transform Tools > Crop* in the image window and enter in the
dialog :

- Position : 0 , 0
- Size : 400 , 400

Double-click inside the selection rectangle or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
to complete cropping.

[image]

Comment: And if you want to go the other direction (make the image larger without upscaling it), it's "Image" > "Canvas Size".